# Application of operator theory in ODE and PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory

I am looking for references of applications of operator theory (especially spectral theory) in ODE, PDE and possibly SDE.

I have learnt operator theory in the general set up, but only know little about its connection to DE.

Comment: It is used a lot in Quantum Mechanics...almost all quantum mechanics

Comment: @TylerHG Thank you. But I don't have a physics background and I am not interested in  the applications in quantum mechanics. I am looking for a mathematical treatment on that subject.

Comment: A nice book is [**Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and Partial differential equations**](http://www.mai.liu.se/~betur/Books/Brezis%20-%20Functional%20Analysis,%20Sobolev%20Spaces%20and%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations.pdf]), by Haim Brezis. I also recommend that you have, at least as a reference, Lars Hörmander's **The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators**, it is a treatise in 4 volumes.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I've been consulting Hoermander's books, but it is not easy to find the materials I need in those volumes.

Answer (score 2):

This answer has been replaced by a link, with similar content:

- ### [Operator Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/examples.htm)

The reason is that adding more and more examples does not fit well into the margins
available with Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Aren't link-only answers discouraged or is it that the original question is too broad for Mathematics Stack Exchange?